# python: converting an egg-info directory to dist-info

Tags: python-wheel

I am working on an existing python application inside of a virtualenv environment. It is already set up to use wheel within its deployment.

I have added another module which my application now needs, and this module only exists in `egg` format. It is currently installed among all the other modules within `./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, and an `egg-info` directory exists for it.

My question is this: how do I convert this one `egg-info` directory to `wheel` format, so that it gets included in the application's deployment when I do the following? ...

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r XXXXXXXX
```

Assuming I have installed a module under `./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/the-module-1.2.3.egg-info`, what are the steps to convert that module to `dist-info`?

Note that I don't see any `*.egg` file for that module, only the `egg-info` directory.

Thank you.